# Fixing "ReferenceError: navigator is not defined"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm currently learning how to make PWA. Now I am stuck in the service worker. The logs said that navigator is not defined. How do I define the navigator?

I've read that navigator is.. a feature in browser? cmiiw. Then I should not install anything on my app. I tried moving the code to my landing page (home.ejs), to my entry point (index.js) but none worked. I also made the sw.js file on root folder. I've also read the tutorial from [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) but I can't get my head around it.

Here's the log

```
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  > sakamichi-akb-chords@1.0.0 start /home/emil/Documents/Chord PWA
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  > node index.js
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  /home/emil/Documents/Chord PWA/index.js:5
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
5:03:23 AM web.1 |                         ^
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
5:03:23 AM web.1 |      at Object.<anonymous> (/home/emil/Documents/Chord PWA/index.js:5:24)
5:03:23 AM web.1 |      at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
5:03:23 AM web.1 |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
5:03:23 AM web.1 |      at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
5:03:23 AM web.1 |      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
5:03:23 AM web.1 |      at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
5:03:23 AM web.1 |      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
5:03:23 AM web.1 |      at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
5:03:23 AM web.1 |      at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm
5:03:23 AM web.1 |   ERR!
5:03:23 AM web.1 |   Linux 4.15.0-50-generic
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! 
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! node v8.10.0
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! sakamichi-akb-chords@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! Exit status 1
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! 
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! Failed at the sakamichi-akb-chords@1.0.0 start script 'node index.js'.
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sakamichi-akb-chords package,
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR!
5:03:23 AM web.1 |   Tell the author that this fails on your system:
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR!     node index.js
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR!
5:03:23 AM web.1 |   You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR!     npm bugs sakamichi-akb-chords
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm 
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  ERR!     npm owner ls sakamichi-akb-chords
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm
5:03:23 AM web.1 |   ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
5:03:23 AM web.1 |  npm ERR!     /home/emil/Documents/Chord PWA/npm-debug.log
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
5:03:23 AM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

And here is my index.js

```js
const path = require ('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const express = require('express')

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}

express()
    .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
    .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
    .set('view engine', 'ejs')
    .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/home'))
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

Any helps? A brief explanation would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Node runs on the server, not in a browser, so `navigator` is not available.

Comment: How do I make it available then?

Comment: You can't. You are trying to run code intended for a browser on the server, that's not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

## React & Sever Side Rendering

If you're doing server side rendering then you need to call navigator in a function that is run on the client side.

For example, with React.js I wanted to run a JS function which determines if the device was mobile so I could do a one off inline style like this:

```
<h2 style={{
    fontSize: this.state.isMob ? '2rem' : '4.5vw',
}}>
```

Now the function uses navigator so I can't just call `fontSize: isMob() ?...`. Instead I call it in the lifecycle method `ComponentDidMount()` because this runs on the client side, set it to the state, then use `this.state.isMob`.

Caveat here is that you will get a flicker after the page loads because it needs to re-render. So if it has an effect on any components that are "above the fold" then you will be sad.

Perhaps not a great example (use CSS instead) but an example nonetheless.